# Thread or Cursors c# Loading CSV files

Tags: c#

I have a code. But, due to my limited knowledge. i researched and realised i can use wait cursor and background thread while waiting the items to be loaded. how can i implement the use cursor or thread in this example?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/screenshot20120617at243.png/

Comment: What do you mean by "cursor"? A cursor is the pointer - the mouse, you know. What does it have to do with threads, or CSV files?

Comment: wait cursor or background thread?

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Please copy+paste code as text

Comment: while the loading the data... show some form of notification for the user. i will copy and paste the code.

Comment: And where did you get this code? That code isn't very good - so I wouldn't be using it as an example or a guide.

Comment: my code is already functional. i just want to add a waiting cursor or implement using a background thread to indicate the data is loading. i dont wish to re write the code all over again. i think just a small modification will do.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is your answer. Google it or see the link in Kane's answer to MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with CSV files I would strongly recommend using a 3rd party library - [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) is one that I have used before and believe it to be excellent as parsing Excel files. In terms of executing the work / parsing it will depend on which version of the .NET framework you are using and if it is a web application or a thick client app.

Assuming that your application is .NET 2.0+ and a Winforms / WPF application you would be best using the `BackgroundWorker` class. There are a ton of examples on Google in using it and the MSDN documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx